# Unable to access methods in an exported class in a class from a class where it is imported in JavaScript

Tags: cypress

This is a JavaScript file that has a class written using Cypress and exported.

```
export class StudentMapping {
   studentsubjectid = "div[id='sid']";
   studentgradeNum = "div[id='sgrd']";

   enterstudentsubjectid() {
     cy.get(this.studentsubjectId).type('SND891');
   }

   entergradeNum() {
     cy.get(this.studentgradeNum).type('D');
   }
}
```

This is another javascript file that has a class. Here, previous class is imported.

```
import StudentMapping from '../../students/studentMap';

    class StudentDetails {
       studentcode = "div[id='scode']";
       studentname = "div[id='sname']";

       StudentMapping.enterstudentsubjectid();
       StudentMapping.entergradeNum();
    }
```

The below lines are showing the error 'Unexpected keyword or identifier.ts(1434)'.

```
   StudentMapping.enterstudentsubjectid();
   StudentMapping.entergradeNum();
```

Unable to call the methods from imported class. Even I used extends keyword:
class StudentDetails extends StudentMapping

Even though, the same error is prompting. Is there a way to use the methods from the exported class from a class where it has been imported?

Comment: They're not static methods, why would they be accessible on the class? With `class StudentDetails extends StudentMapping` they'd be accessible via `this`, but it's not clear whether that's in any sense _correct_.

Answer (score 2):

To use one class inside another, use either [inheritance](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_class_inheritance.asp)

```js
class StudentDetails extends StudentMapping {
  studentcode = "div[id='scode']";
  studentname = "div[id='sname']";

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.enterstudentsubjectid();
    this.entergradeNum();
  }
}
```

or composition

```js
class StudentDetails {
  studentcode = "div[id='scode']";
  studentname = "div[id='sname']";

  constructor() {
    const studentMapping = new StudentMapping();
    studentMapping.enterstudentsubjectid();
    studentMapping.entergradeNum();
  }
}
```